# Am I calculating the probability correctly with this code within Java?

Tags: java, probability

I am trying to calculate the total probability of an investment returning positive after a given number of periods. It's been a while since I've done probability, so I don't really remember it all that well. Am I doing it right? I am getting fairly low numbers.

```
double totalProbPos = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < maxPeriods; i++) {
    totalProbPos *= (probPos / 100);
}
totalProbPos = round(totalProbPos);
System.out.println("\nThe probability that your investment will return positive after " + maxPeriods + " periods is: \n    " + totalProbPos + "%.");
```

Where:`maxPeriods, probPos` are given by the user.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `*= 1 - probPos / 100.0`? You could also just skip the loop and just compute `double totalProbPos = (1 - probPos / 100.0) ^ maxPeriods`.

Comment: You may give a link to th eformula e.g on wiki

Comment: @Blender I just tried `Math.pow((1 - probPos / 100), maxPeriods);` but now it is even lower. I am testing with `probPos = 54;` and now I get 0.002004% as a result, which can't be right because When I am running the simulation, I am getting positive a lot more than that many times.

Comment: @Xzar: I don't know much about how investment deals with probabilities, so you either have to do `total = 1 - prob ^ trials` or `total = 1 - (1 - prob) ^ trials`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Blender why do you subtract `(1 - prob) ^ trials` from 1?

Comment: @Xzar: `prob` is the probability that an event occurs if you do one trial. `prob ^ n` is the probability that an event occurs `n` times in a row. `(1 - prob) ^ n` is the probability that an event does not occur `n` times in a row, so `1 - (1 - prob) ^ n` is the probability that an event occurs at least once in `n` trials.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it is not well posed, from what I can tell. The author hasn't clearly specified what he/she is trying to accomplish, and it's unrealistic to expect respondents to guess what it is. This question would be improved very much by giving more detail about the problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
totalProbPos *= (probPos / 100);
```

It is better to cast one of the operands to double to avoid [integer divison](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-int-div.html) issue (assuming you care about decimal points)

```
totalProbPos *= ((double)probPos / 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess (with the emphasis on "guess") that the way to approach this problem is to try to derive a probability distribution for the return on investment at the end time. Then you just find the probability that the return is greater than zero (i.e., integral from 0 to infinity of the probability density). The probability distribution for return at the end time might be something like a Gaussian (normal) distribution, or it might be a distribution over discrete states, as given by a Markov chain. Maybe the original problem statement has some info which would help one figure out what to do.